# I'm not able to DeAuth a Client (Aireplay-ng)

Tags: wifi, aircrack-ng, deauth-attack, airodump-ng

I'm trying to perform a De-authentication attack on my own network and client. However, the client never disconnects and I cannot boot the client from the AP.

I'm running:

```
aireplay-ng -0 0 -a [BSSID] wlan0 -c [TARGET MAC]
```

- I'm close to the client
- Target is a normal laptop computer
- AP is an ARRIS (I've been able to capture handshakes easily from this AP)
- I've sent endless deauth packets for 5+ minutes, client refuses to disconnect.
- I'm using an ALFA adapter with the Ralink RT3070 chipset (802.11b/g/n) @ 2.4Ghz.

Something I'm missing?

Comment: run a packet capture to start your troubleshooting process

Comment: Hi, my goal is not to take the handshake of the connection (where I'm completely capable-or I understood not correct?-) but the fact of disconnect the client for proposing an evil twin attack.

Comment: yep, I know, but you want to ensure that you are sending the packets

Comment: sorry how to do than?

Comment: look into wireshark - if you want to play with packets, you're really going to need that tool

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are transmitting on the correct channel? This is the most common problem I see in the wild.

Comment: @schroeder I tried to make an attack to my phone and monitoring with wireshark, what I see in wireshark is a strongly increasing the number column, and with info I see is written: "Deauthentication, S=0, FN=0, Flags=..... and is likes so. I need to search something else specific? Thanks!

to multithr3at3d I am definetly sending the correct cannel in airodump'ng and infact I'm seeing devices connected. Or you meant to add the channel in aireplay'ng? there there is the -c of targetted mac thanks!

Comment: I think that firewalls block this kind of attack on modern routers, at least aireplay doesn't work anymore but I don't exclude that could exist other tools more powerful than aireplay nowadays.

Comment: Like what for example? @Virgula

Comment: @Joe JamWifi seems working , but it's for OSx: https://github.com/0x0XDev/JamWiFi

Comment: Some routers support encrypted management frames. This can prevent deauth attacks